# How can I initialise a dynamic nested object in kotlin?

Tags: generics, interface, kotlin

I'm looking to create an object structure that has a dynamic class that I would want to change:

Top level:

```
data class TopLevel(
  var myCustomClass1: MyCustomClass1,
  var myCustomClass2: MyCustomClass2)
```

Second level:

```
data class MyCustomClass2(var dynamicClass: DynamicClass)
```

The `DynamicClass` is the the one I want to change.e.g I may want to use `DynamicClass` or `DynamicClass2` within `MyCustomClass2`.

What is the best way to do this using kotlin?

Comment: what is your goal with this?

Comment: Within MyCustomClass2 I want to be able to change which object is passed into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Kotlin is a statically typed language, you'll need to find some way to describe your abstract class, e.g. by using an interface:

```
interface IDynamicClass

class DynamicClass : IDynamicClass
class DynamicClass2 : IDynamicClass

data class MyCustomClass2(var dynamicClass: IDynamicClass)
```

This allows you to instantiate the `MyCustomClass2` with any instance implementing the `IDynamicClass` interface:

```
MyCustomClass2(DynamicClass())
MyCustomClass2(DynamicClass2())
```